# Trouble getting input for object array

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am trying to create a class that receives data about a person's name, exam subject, and exam score. I have these classes so far:

APExam:

```
public class APExam {
   //instance variables
   private String mySubject;
   private int myScore;
   
   //constructors
   public APExam(String subject, int score) {
      mySubject = subject;
      myScore = score;
   }
   public APExam() {
      mySubject = "";
      myScore = 1;
   }
   
   //getters and setters
   public void setSubject(String s) {
      mySubject = s;
   }
   public String getSubject() {
      return mySubject;
   }
   public void setScore(int score) {
      myScore = score;
   }
   public int getScore() {
      return myScore;
   }
   
   //compareTo
   public String compareTo(int s) {
      if(myScore == s)
         return "Scores are equal.";
      else if(myScore > s)
         return "The first score is greater than the second score.";  
      else 
         return "The second score is greater than the first score.";
   }
   
   //equals
   public boolean equals(String str) {
      return mySubject.equals(str);
   }
   
   //toString
   public String toString() {
      return "Subject: " + mySubject + "\nScore: " + myScore;
   }
}
```

APStudent:

```
public class APStudent {
   //instance variables
   private String myFirstName;
   private String myLastName;
   private ArrayList<APExam> myExams = new ArrayList<APExam>();
   
   //constructors
   public APStudent(String fname, String lname) {
      myFirstName = fname;
      myLastName = lname;
   }
   public APStudent() {
      myFirstName = "";
      myLastName = "";
   }
   
   //getters and setters
   public void setFirstName(String fname) {
      myFirstName = fname;
   } 
   public String getFirstName() {
      return myFirstName;
   }
   public void setLastName(String lname) {
      myLastName = lname;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return myLastName;
   }
   public ArrayList<APExam> getExams() {
      return myExams;
   }
   
   //addExam
   public void addExam(APExam ex) {
      myExams.add(ex);
   }
   
   //computeExamAverage
   public double computeExamAverage(List<APExam> exams) {
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < exams.size(); i++) {
         sum += exams.get(i).getScore();
      }
      return (double) sum / exams.size();
   }
   
   //findHighestExamScore
   public int findHighestExamScore(List<APExam> exams) {
      int max = exams.get(0).getScore();
      for(APExam ex : exams) {
         if(ex.getScore() > max) {
            max = ex.getScore();
         }
      }
      return max;
   }
   
   //numberOfFives
   public int numberOfFives(List<APExam> exams) {
      int fiveCount = 0;
      for(APExam ex : exams) {
         if(ex.getScore() == 5) {
            fiveCount++;
         }
      }
      return fiveCount;
   }
}
```

ArrayListTest:

```
public class ArrayListTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //instance variables
      final String QUIT = "end";
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      ArrayList<APExam> myExams = new ArrayList<APExam>();
      APStudent student = new APStudent();
      String fname, lname, sub, input = "";
      int score;
      
      //prompt for info
      System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
      fname = sc.nextLine();
      student.setFirstName(fname);
      System.out.print("\nEnter last name: ");
      lname = sc.nextLine();
      student.setLastName(lname);
      while(!input.equals(QUIT)) {
         APExam ap = new APExam();
         System.out.print("\nEnter exam subject or 'end' to quit: ");
         input = sc.nextLine();
         sub = input;
         ap.setSubject(sub);
         System.out.print("\nEnter exam score: ");
         score = sc.nextInt();
         ap.setScore(score);
         student.addExam(ap);
         sc.nextLine();
         
      }
      
      //display information
      System.out.println(student.getExams());
      System.out.println("Name: " + student.getFirstName() + " " + student.getLastName());
      System.out.println("Exam average score: " + student.computeExamAverage(myExams));
      System.out.println("Highest score: " + student.findHighestExamScore(myExams));
      System.out.println("Number of fives: " + student.numberOfFives(myExams));
      
      System.out.println();
      
      
      for(int i = 0; i < myExams.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println(myExams.get(i));
      }
      
      //prompt for search
      System.out.println("1 sequential search" 
                        + "\n2 binary search"
                        + "\n3 exit");
      input = sc.nextLine();
      while(!((input.equals("1") || input.equals("2") || input.equals("3")))) {
         switch(input) {
            case "1":
               sequentialSearch(myExams, 3);
               break;
            case "2":
               binarySearch(myExams, 2);
               break;
            case "3":
               break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For some reason in the ArrayListTest class it doesn't create an APExam object with the inputted scores and subjects. Is there something wrong with the while loop? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing an empty list to `computeExamAvarage` etc. instead of using the instance's own `this.myExams`? The `myExams` you declared in `ArrayListTest` is *not* the same `myExams` that is in `APStudend`.

Comment: Hey, @Matt look at my answer and let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: @AP11 I saw your answer. It worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are for some reason passing variable `List<APExam> exams` into your functions. When you are doing that you are passing a empty `ArrayList<APExam>` and that's why it throws a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You shouldn't pass anything and just use the `APStudent`'s `myExams` list.

```
public double computeExamAverage() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (APExam myExam : myExams) {
        sum += myExam.getScore();
    }
    return sum / myExams.size();
}

public int findHighestExamScore() {
    int max = 0;
    for(APExam exam : myExams) {
        if(exam.getScore() > max) max = exam.getScore();
    }
    return max;
}

public int numberOfFives() {
    return (int) myExams.stream().filter(apExam -> apExam.getScore() == 5).count();
}
```

EDIT: I would like to comment on your main method too. You should use the parametrized constructors instead of default one and setters. And you should check on the input being `"end"` before you ask for grade.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String QUIT = "end"; // not really necessary, but ok
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName, lastName, subject;
    int score;

    //prompt for info
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    firstName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nEnter last name: ");
    lastName = sc.nextLine();
    APStudent student = new APStudent(firstName, lastName); // use of parametrized constructor
    while(true) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter exam subject or 'end' to quit: ");
        subject = sc.nextLine();
        if (subject.equals(QUIT)) break; // check if user wants to end it
        System.out.print("\nEnter exam score: ");
        score = sc.nextInt();
        student.addExam(new APExam(subject, score));  // use of parametrized constructor
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    sc.close(); // never forget to close Scanner

    //display information etc.
}
```